# I want my android application to show the latest data from backend

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

I want my android application to show the latest data from backend, I can make the api call in a interval but this not feels like a right solution. I want to make the api call only if there is a change in that api.

Comment: you could set up a websocket. Implementation will depent on used websocket library.

Answer (score 1):

Send a push notification to app when data is changed and then once you acknowledge that notification you can make api call to get the latest data.

For notifications you can use:

1. Firebase sdk (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-
   message)
2. Use Aws SNS in the backend to send notification to firebase/apns